# XQuery in the free version of Saxon

Tags: java, xquery, saxon

I'd like to know whether someone has any experience with XQuery as it is supported in the [free version of Saxon](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/). Can it generally be presumed to be complete and usable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I have found the free version to be fast and stable.

The XQuery Test Suite has thousands of conformance tests.  You can see how Saxon performs here:
http://dev.w3.org/2006/xquery-test-suite/PublicPagesStagingArea/XQTSReportSimple.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to use the complete set of XQuery specification (update, scripting, and full-text), you may be interested by Zorba open-source XQuery processor: http://www.zorba-xquery.com.